# set Multiple "jwk-set-uri" for my spring resource server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2, oauth2resourceserver

I have been developing this mobile app for a long time now which uses microservices architecture on the backend ( spring boot 2.4.2 ) . I have been able to set my microservices as resource servers which validate google tokens and everything works as expected in android version . Incidentally , I'm working on ios version and apple store imposes a rule to add apple sign in feature to my app .

Currently google sign in is working just fine with this line in application.properties file  :

*spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri = https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs*

However with this apple store rule I have to set another jwk-set-uri "https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys" .

So my resource server can validate both token types apple and google .

How can I just Do that exactly . I have been looking on the web for a precise solution but with no avail .

Can someone please help me out . Any kind of help would be much appreciated .

Cheers .